# How to create thumbnail in laravel

Tags: laravel

I am new to 'Laravel'. I have generated thumbnail thing in core php using 'ffmpeg'. But don't how to do this in 'Laravel'.

Help me out. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, this is not a Code Request website. Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how to ask new questions.

Comment: http://image.intervention.io/   this may help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.6: Create image thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451911/laravel-5-6-create-image-thumbnails)

Comment: Paste your code here, have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a popular package `Intervention Image` http://image.intervention.io

Follow the installation here: http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation

It's so easy to generate a thumbnail with this package.