# Saving Images in two size in Laravel Livewire

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, intervention

I have a form where I upload images using Laravel Livewire.

In my class I can save the files in original size using:

```
$filenames = collect($this->photos)->map->store('posts');
```

The issue that I faced is that I don't know how to save the same images (with same name as above) in another folder (thumbnail folder) in another size. For instance, width 200px.

Comment: There is a package which I recommend it a-lot it will help you to store more than conversion of the photo and there are a lot of features 

The name of the page is Laravel-medialibrary from Spatie and I will leave the link below

https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v9/introduction

Comment: Take reference from question [Laravel 5.6: Create image thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451911/laravel-5-6-create-image-thumbnails)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.6: Create image thumbnails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50451911/laravel-5-6-create-image-thumbnails)

Answer (score 0):

I have used this with Laravel 8 and it works. I can't see what you have before this code but you can iterate through your photos and save 2 images, one in the parent folder and one resized in a "thumbnail" folder;

```
$ext = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
$date = new Carbon;
$folder = "photos";

// Save original file
$orig_filename = $date->format('YmdHisv') . '.' . $ext;
$img_url = $image->storeAs('public/' . $folder, $orig_filename);

// Create and store thumbnail
$thumbnail = $image->storeAs('public/' . $folder . '/thumbnails', $orig_filename);
$thumb_path = Storage::path('public/' . $folder . '/thumbnails/' . $orig_filename);
$thumb_img = Image::make($thumb_path)->resize(150, 93, function ($constraint) {
        $constraint->aspectRatio();
});
$thumb_img->save($path);
```

This is the package [Intervention\Image](https://intervention.io/) and [here](https://artisansweb.net/create-thumbnail-in-laravel-using-intervention-image-library/) is a great tutorial on that.